# How to prevent users from taking screenshots on android devices version < 3.0

Tags: android

In my applications (run on devices < 3.0) want to prevent/restrict users to screen capturing to make it more secured. I want to implement this in application programmatically. I have implemented below code but it doesnt work for devices < 3.0

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

Please help or suggest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i have same issue with me.
LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE is not works with samsung devices with android OS version<3.0

you can check like this

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT != android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD && !android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER.equalsIgnoreCase("samsung")) 
                getWindow( ).setFlags( LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE );
```

Comment: thanks but i want this functionality to work on gingerbread devices also.